# Scrapy fails to filter out duplicate urls

Tags: python, scrapy

I have implemented custom middleware in an attempt to filter out duplicate URLs when crawling using Scrapy, but it seems that the request_seen method is not called for every URL.

My middleware writes to a txt file in order to maintain a list of unique URLs across different crawls. However, the middleware is not being called for each URL. I identified one such URL and included print statements to trace its path; the print statement in the Spider is being printed to the console, but none of the ones in the middleware are. Below is my code.

**Spider**

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

from ..items import SBItem

class SBSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "sales-betty"
    allowed_domains = ["www.med.nyu.edu"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.med.nyu.edu/az-departments-divisions"]

    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_url', follow=True), )

    custom_settings = {
        'DEPTH_LIMIT': 1,
        'DUPEFILTER_CLASS': 'salesbetty_scrapy.duplicate_filter.CustomFilter'
    }

    def parse_url(self, response):
        for link in LinkExtractor(allow=self.allowed_domains, unique=True).extract_links(response):
            item = SBItem()
            item["url"] = link.url
            if link.url == "http://www.med.nyu.edu/school/about-us":
                print "FOUND ABOUT US IN CORE SCRAPER"
            print link.url
```

**Middleware**

```
import os

from scrapy.dupefilter import RFPDupeFilter

class CustomFilter(RFPDupeFilter):
    """A dupe filter that considers specific ids in the url"""

    def request_seen(self, request):
        if request.url == "http://www.med.nyu.edu/school/about-us":
            print "FOUND ABOUT US"
        visited_urls = self.get_unique_urls()
        if request.url in visited_urls:
            if request.url == "http://www.med.nyu.edu/school/about-us":
                print "FOUND ABOUT US IN VISITED"
            return True
        else:
            self.add_url(request.url)
            if request.url == "http://www.med.nyu.edu/school/about-us":
                print "FOUND ABOUT US FOR FIRST TIME"
            return False

    def get_unique_urls(self):
        urls = []
        if os.path.exists("visited_urls.txt"):
            with open("visited_urls.txt") as f:
                urls = f.readlines()
        visited = set()
        for url in urls:
            visited.add(url)

        return visited

    def add_url(self, url):
        with open("visited_urls.txt", 'a') as f:
            f.write(url + "\n")
        if url == "http://www.med.nyu.edu/school/about-us":
            print "FOUND ABOUT US AND ADDED"
```

Comment: Can you provide complete logs of a crawl?

Comment: While running your spider, I see that the Request to "http://www.med.nyu.edu/school/about-us" is filtered by DepthMiddleware, with debug lines like _"2016-10-18 14:34:53 [scrapy] DEBUG: Ignoring link (depth > 1): http://www.med.nyu.edu/school/about-us "_. Is your `'DEPTH_LIMIT': 1`, setting really needed?

Comment: @paultrmbrth I need some control over depth as I don't want this to run indefinitely. Is the middleware called after the parse_url function? If so, is there a better way to collect all the links the spider visits other than calling `print link.url` at the end of parse_url?